# Hortonworks Sandbox URL not working

Tags: hadoop, installation, hortonworks-data-platform

I downloaded the latest sandbox from this url - http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/ and played it with my VM Player. I have reached till the screen where URL is displayed. Now when I try to login with that URL I am getting 'Web page not available' (chrome), 'Can't reach page' (IE), 'The connection has timed out' (Firefox) error basically not working in any browser.

Can someone help me how to troubleshoot this?

I am using Windows 10, VMPlayer 7.3 and here is the page that gets displayed in VM Player - 
[image]

Comment: What is the link you are using?

Comment: Well the link displayed is what I have used for pinging i.e. http://192.168.183.141.

Comment: It could be because you are using old version of VM Player. What is the network adapter you are using in VM Player, NAT or Bridged or Hostonly?

Comment: The network adapter I am using is NAT. The VM Player too I have updated to the latest version i.e. 7.1.3. Still facing the same error.

Comment: You can hit Alt+F5 and get into terminal of the VM and check if iptables are running by using `service iptables status` and `service ip6tables status`

Comment: On running either of the commands I am getting the result as - iptables: Firewall is not running. I then proceeded to start the service with command service iptables start but then I get the WARNING- iptables: No config file. Further searching on it, I did iptables -L and see that it is set as ACCEPT for chain INPUT,FORWARD and OUTPUT. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Windows 10, VMPlayer 15 and HDP Sandbox 3.0.1.

Setting the network adapter to Bridged Networking and restart the virtual Machine can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods

1. Ping 192.168.183.141. If you are getting any reply, then problem with VMNetwork adopter configurations
2. If it is not pinging check your firewall settings

Last try this...repair your VMPlayer (it will configure default services) or remove and re-install VMPlayer

Comment: Both the methods aren't working. Ping is resulting in request timed out. I have done both repairing and re-installing but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Make an entry in hosts file in windows with sandbox ip address and assign name

192.168.183.141 hdpsandbox

Then open your browser and type hdpsandbox:8888

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. Still getting page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i had the same problem. It is actually not related to the VM or the browser. It is actually the Network adapter installed by the Vm which allows it to use host's machines networks.

In my case i was using Vmware so it had installed two network adapters

[image]

So all i had to do was to Enable them.

**[Windows Users]**

1. Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
2. Find the Vmware Network Adapter
3. Right click on it and Enable them
4. Done Try to open the Url now

Cheers!